# Lost code when deleting a conda environment in Anacaonda Navigator

Tags: file, anaconda, recovery, navigator

I had an  Python 3.7.1 environment i had created in Anaconda Navigator. Overtime i noticed that i had created a few extra environments with the same  name but different capitals so i went to remove these names in navigator, when i went back to my folder where i store all the code i had under development it was gone. Quite a lot of work.

I was using VScode as a development environment

Is there anyway i can recover my development files by restoring the deleted environment or some other process?